# Interaction between DUXPreFlightStatusWidget and DUXPreflightChecklistController is not working as advertised

Tags: ios, swift, dji-sdk

According to https://developer.dji.com/api-reference/ios-uilib-api/Widgets/PreFlightStatusWidget.html:

"Tapping on status text will toggle between show and hide DUXPreflightChecklistController."

When I tap on the status text in the widget, the DUXPreflightChecklistController is not shown.  Also, if I manually show the DUXPreflightChecklistController, there is a close button in the top right corner of the panel but tapping it does not hide the panel.

What is the proper way to configure this panel?

I'm using DJISDK 4.7.1 and DJIUXSDK 4.7.1 with Swift and iOS 12/xCode 10.0.

To provide a bit more detail, I do not want to use the Default Layout but I am using DUXStatusBarViewController.  That is embedded in a UIView across the top of my app.  I cannot find any properties for that controller that would allow me to hook it up to my instance of DUXPreflightChecklistController, which is also embedded in a UIView.

Answer (score 0):

For: DUXPreflightChecklistController

I'd just solved that

```
var preflightChecklistController: DUXPreflightChecklistController!
weak var preFlightTableView: UITableView!
private var compassItemIndex: Int = -1
private var storageItemIndex: Int = -1

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    preflightChecklistController = DUXPreflightChecklistController()
    addChild(preflightChecklistController)
}

func renderChecklist() {
    if let checklistVC = preflightChecklistController {
        for subview in checklistVC.view.subviews {
            if subview.isKind(of: UITableView.self) {
                if let tableView = subview as? UITableView {
                    self.view.addSubview(tableView)
                    preFlightTableView = tableView
                }
            }
        }

        guard let checklistManager = checklistVC.checklistManager else { return }
        let itemList = checklistManager.preFlightChecklistItems
        for (index, item) in itemList.enumerated() {
            if let _ = item as? DUXStorageCapacityChecklistItem {
                storageItemIndex = index
            }
            if let _ = item as? DUXCompassChecklistItem {
                compassItemIndex = index
            }
        }
        preFlightTableView.reloadData()
        checklistManager.startCheckingList()
    }
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(true)
    renderChecklist()
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    guard preFlightTableView != nil else { return }
    if let compassCell = preFlightTableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(item: compassItemIndex, section: 0)) {
        for view in compassCell.subviews {
            if let button = view as? UIButton, button.titleLabel?.text == "Calibrate" {
                button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(doActionForSpecifiedBTN(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
                break
            }
        }
    }
    if let storageCell = preFlightTableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(item: storageItemIndex, section: 0)) {
        for view in storageCell.subviews {
            if let button = view as? UIButton, button.titleLabel?.text == "Format" {
                button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(doActionForSpecifiedBTN(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
                break
            }
        }
    }
}

@objc func doActionForSpecifiedBTN(sender: UIButton) {
    guard let btnTitle = sender.titleLabel else { return }
    switch btnTitle.text {
    case "Calibrate":
        // your func goes here
    case "Format":
        // your func goes here
    default:
        break
    }
}
```